# SpriteKit/Scenekit TouchesBegan or GestureRecognizer

Tags: sprite-kit, scenekit

Is there a best practice when it comes to games for overriding either touchesBegan etc. in your scene and node subclasses as opposed to using the gestureRecognizers?

I know Apple's templates have the `override func touchesXXXX` methods in them and this allows for a bit more control (unless using custom recognizers). But a lot of tutorials seem to use the GestureRecognizer approach.

Is this primarily tutorials making things easier, or is it more common to use the GestureRecognizer route to remove some of the complexity? I know this could come down to developer preference, but I'm looking for a 'Best Practice' - do Apple actually suggest one way over the other when making games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wonder the same thing too - it gets even more interesting when you mix SceneKit and SpriteKit together. I haven't seen any official documentation suggesting one or the other, as they are really for slightly different things. You'll find the Xcode game templates use one or the other (or both, in the case of a cross platform spritekit game).

I think the reason most of the tutorials and blogs use the GestureRecognizer approach is that it does a lot of the work for you, but when you get into more complicated use cases, you may find you need to handle the touches manually and handle gestures yourself (theres a few examples floating around the internet) as I had to for a particular project.

I have also read on a few blogs, that sometimes using the touches approach AND GestureRecognizers together can give incorrect results (specifically missing touches), but that could be stale information - it's worth checking though if you did decided to use both.

So to answer the question, I don't believe there is an official best practice for this, as both are valid and current methods. I'd say use whichever you think fits better and makes the code as simple and clean as possible.

Comment: I agree that using both direct touch recognition and UIGestureRecognizers can lead to trouble.  If there is a best practice, it's probably that you should use gesture recognizers if your UI would naturally work with them, and do direct touch recognition for more complicated use cases.  (I.e., same as just using normal UIKit.)  Games tend to have more specific UI needs compared to, say, a productivity app, so you'll probably see more explicit touch tracking in the games space, but there are probably many use cases, even in games, where gesture recognizers are fine.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is respond to touches on the screen, use the 3 standard 'touches' methods.

If you need to respond to distinct swipes, pans, pinches etc then you'll need gesture recognisers.